# Recursively defined numbers vs geometric series

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $a,b\in{\mathbb Z}^{\ge0}$ and $h\in{\mathbb R}(d_1,d_2)$ be such that
$$a\ge b, \quad h(d_1,d_2)>0~~\forall\,d_1,d_2\in{\mathbb Z}^+, \quad \lim_{d_1,d_2\longrightarrow\infty}\frac{h(d_1,d_2)}{d_1^ad_2^a/(d_1\!+\!d_2)^b}\in{\mathbb R}^+\,.$$
The limit statement means that these fractions are within $\epsilon$ of some number for all $d_1,d_2\!\ge\!d(\epsilon)$.

For $d\!=\!1,2,\ldots$, define the numbers $n_d\!\in\!{\mathbb R}^+$ inductively by 
$$n_1=1, \qquad
n_d=\sum_{\begin{subarray}{c}d_1+d_2=d\\ d_1,d_2\ge1\end{subarray}}\!\!\!\!
h(d_1,d_2)n_{d_1}n_{d_2} \quad\forall~d>1.$$
Are the numbers $\sqrt[d]{n_d}$ eventually increasing? In other words, is there $d^*\!\in\!{\mathbb Z}^+$ such that 
$$\sqrt[d]{n_d}\le\sqrt[d+1]{n_{d+1}} \qquad\forall~ d\ge d^*.$$
This is true if $h(d_1,d_2)=d_1^a d_2^a/(d_1\!+\!d_2)^a$. In general, these roots are bounded above and below away from zero.

Comment: Dear Aleksey, Could you say a little more about what this has to do with the recursion relations from Gromov-Witten theory?  That might make it easier to put this question in context.

Comment: I am sure that you know this already, but you may as well replace the initial condition, $n_1=1$, by the condition that $n_1>0$.  The set of solutions is invariant under the transformation $n_d^{\text{new}} = a^d n_d^{\text{old}}$ for $a>0$.  Also the conclusion you want to prove is invariant under this transformation.

Comment: Okay, here is another silly observation.  Assume that $a>0$.  By your hypothesis, there exists $d(\epsilon)$ such that for all $d \geq d(\epsilon)$, also $h(d,d) \geq d^{2a-b}/u$ for some $u>0$. Then, for every $v>1$, there is a larger integer $d^*$ such that for all $d\geq d^*$, also $d^{2a-b}/u >v$.  Then $\sqrt{2d}{n_{2d}} \geq v\cdot \sqrt{d}{n_d}$.  Thus, even if the sequence $(\sqrt{d}{n_d})$ is not increasing, nonetheless it has many increasing subsequences.

Comment: Typo correction:  The LaTeX was bad for the final 2 sentences.  It should have read "Then $\sqrt[2d]{n_{2d}} \geq \sqrt[d]{n_d}$.  Thus, even if the sequence $(\sqrt[d]{n_d})_d$ is not increasing, nonetheless it has many increasing subsequences."

Comment: In your applications, do you have any *a priori* upper bounds on $h(d_1,d_2)$ for $d_1+d_2 < 2d(\epsilon)$?  If so, you could try to make my previous remark into an induction proof.

Comment: I just want to confirm: when you write $h\in \mathbb{R}(d_1,d_2)$, do you mean that $h$ is a rational function of $d_1$ and $d_2$?

Comment: @JasonStarr. Since this sequence is bounded above and below, I do not find it too surprising that it has many increasing subsequences. Of course, it could be just decreasing. This would be fine for my purposes too, since I actually want to know that $\sqrt[d]{n_d}$ has a limit (in relation to my question from 2 days ago).

Comment: @JasonStarr. . With a specific and somewhat ugly $h$, this recursion is equivalent to Kontsevich's formula for $2^dn_d/(3d−1)!$; there is more in my post from 2 days ago. While only this specific $h$ is relevant in this context, I find the general question interesting and more natural. I realize that $n_1$ can equivalently be taken to be any positive real.

Comment: @JasonStarr. I do mean that $h$ is a rational function of $d_1$ and $d_2$. It can be assumed to be symmetric. In the context of Kontsevich's formula $h(d_1,d_2)\!=\!f(d_1\!+\!d_2,d_1d_2)/g(d_1\!+\!d_2)$ for some polynomials $f$ and $g$. Since the number of $(d_1,d_2)$ with $d_1\!+\!d_2\!<\!2d(\epsilon)$ is finite, there is a bound on the corresponding $h(d_1,d_2)$, but it depends on $\epsilon$.